# How to use annotation and avoid xml configuration in spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have designed a packing structure.

- Controller
- Delegates (which is helper class) - this class do all the business and return the value to Controllers.
- Service
- Service Implementation
- DAO
- DAO Implementation.

I want to implement autowired (Annotation) concept and would like to avoid xml configuration such as service and DAO configuration on spring-bean.xml.

This code is not working if I want to avoid xml configuration.

I have done those changes

- bean id :loginDelegate, userService, userDao
- added the @Service & @Repository annotation to the corresponding service & DAO implementation.

---

```
@Controller("loginController")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDelegate loginDelegate;

    public LoginDelegate getLoginDelegate() {
        return this.loginDelegate;
    }
    public void setLoginDelegate(LoginDelegate tLoginDelegate) {
        this.loginDelegate = tLoginDelegate;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/login.do",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("<---displayLogin()--->");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
        LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
        model.addObject("loginBean", loginBean);
        return model;
    }
}   

public class LoginDelegate {
     @Autowired
     private IUserService userService;

     public IUserService getUserService() {
         return this.userService;
     }

     public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
         this.userService = userService;
     }

     public boolean isValidUser(String username, String password) throws Exception {
         return userService.isValidUser(username, password);
     }
}

public interface IUserService {
    public boolean isValidUser(UserBean userObj);
    public int addUsers(UserBean userObj);
}

public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {
    @Autowired
    private IUserDao userDao;

    public IUserDao getUserDao()  {
        return this.userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(IUserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public boolean isValidUser(UserBean userObj) {
        return userDao.isExistUser(userObj);
    }

    @Override
    public int addUser(final UserBean userObj) {
        return userDao.saveUserDetails(userObj);    
    }
}

public interface IUserDao {
    public boolean isExistUser(UserBean userObj);
    public int saveUserDetails(UserBean userObj);
}

public class UserDaoImpl implements IUserDao {
    @Autowired
    UserBean userObj;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource ;

    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        return this.dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Java-based configuration if you want to completely get rid of XML-based configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.acme")
public class AppConfig  {
    ...
}
```

1. The above normal Java class when annotated with @Configuration, makes it a 'Spring Configuration class' (analogous to XML-based configuration).
2. @ComponentScan annotation scans for classes annotated with @Component, @Controller, @Service, @Repository classes from the package defined during start-up time to get them registered as Spring beans. This can be done in XML also with `<context:component-scan base-package="com.acme" />`

Refer:http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-instantiating-container-scan